# Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel as Integer)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a main form with all of the selection criteria. If someone selects a year, like 2015, inadvertantly, there is NO data in the SQL Server for that year. When a button is pushed to open a subsequent Form, it will produce a Run_Time Error 2105.  What would I need to add to the following code to alleviate the aforementioned error:

```
 Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.AllowEdits = True
  DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
 End Sub
```

Comment: How does one select a year? Is there a combobox or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
'test for numeric
If IsNumeric(UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value) Then

    'convert to long before comparing to year
    If CLng(UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value) <= Year(Now) Then
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
    End If
End If
```